# What's the policy on a request to add a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, review

While going through some suggested answer edits today I came across one which changed nothing but added the following to the bottom of the answer:

> --- Anybody help me put my question to comment please? I cannot add a comment-----
>
> But why it is 4G byte? 32 address lines can access 2^32 (4G) different
>   address, but every address could be a byte or a word(4byte) 32bit -->
>   4G Byte, when it is a byte 32bit --> 4G * 4 Byte, when it is a word Do
>   you mean there is only 8 data output lines? so every address can only
>   output 8 bits. Why do we have to limit the data lines to 8 lines? Can
>   we make it 32 data output lines?

The comment on the edit was "I cannot add comment, I have a question. please help me add a comment under this question."

I take this as it being a new user who can't comment on the answer, but wanted whoever reviews the edit to comment on it for him.

Two questions:

1. What should I do in this situation? Should I comment for him, or does that encourage misuse of the edit functionality?
2. Is there a process for new users to submit comments for consideration, even if they're not allowed to directly comment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using suggested edits as comments is a nono. Reject with impunity.The one exception is If its *clearly* the op (who is a poor lost soul and is unregistered), and he's lost his cookie.

Don't encourage this.

The right way to do this would likely be to post a *second* question, referring back to the first one (but this would not be a good question anyway). Even as a comment, this might be noise rather than something adding to the original question, so I wouldn't show it too much mercy.

There's no suggested comments mechanism at this point of time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you consider http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/287174 a comment?

Comment: I'd *personally* would have rejected it, as it *should* have been a comment. I don't see the value in rolling it back tho